# Temporarily prevent Sublime Text opening previous tabs/windows on launch?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm aware I can control this behavior generally through User Prefs via `"remember_open_files": true`.

I'm looking for a keypress or Bash command that could prevent the behavior in isolated cases where the previous state of the app causes Sublime to freeze.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved it by removing within Terminal:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Auto Save Session.sublime_session`

With escaped characters, that's:

`~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Local/Auto\ Save\ Session.sublime_session`

If there's a more convenient method, please let me know, and I'll accept your answer. Thank you.